# Who should clean up the stack?

Tags: assembly

I understand that if you do not clean up the stack that you can cause problems later such as memory leaks, ect, and so I wanted to know what is the best way to make sure the  the stack is cleaned up?

Also should it be cleaned by the calling procedure or the called procedure?

Comment: Define what you mean by “clean up the stack”.

Answer (score 2):

It is defined by [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions). For example for `cdecl` caller cleans stack for `stdcall` - callee.

Also not cleaning stack properly is **memory leaking**. It will start causing problems so fast that you will not even notice.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no cleaning of the stack! Stack is temporary program memory. You must only to correct restore the stack pointer register and the base pointer register (depend of calling convention). Stack memory should stay unchanged and will be overwritten at next use!

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you as caller of the procedure to know what to do with the stack and how to pass the arguments. The callee will expect certain things to be set up before the call and may expect you to do things after. This agreement is called a 'calling convention'.  CPU architectures will have a range of calling conventions.

Two commons ones are 'cdecl' and 'pascal'.

In 'cdecl' you push the arguments onto the stack, make the call and then pop the items off.

In 'pascal' the callee is responsible for cleaning up the stack before it returns.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is whatever is consistent w/ the rest or the program; if you are using libraries, or used BY libraries, make sure you're consistent with what they expect.

If you have total control, pick one policy & stick with it across the board.  You could even divide up the work: have each (caller & callee) be responsible for cleaning up what changes it made to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Some conventions require one entry and one exit point per function. Thus it's quite easy to put the cleaning routine at the end.

But it's not necessarily best to actually *clean* the stack, instead of randomizing the contents or putting some sentinel there (float / double that encodes into NaN, or a pointer that's clearly outside the allocated area.) With this you'll detect undefined behavior much faster than forcing clean zeros for every function that doesn't initialize it's parameters. Also you could want to make your malloc/free to detect these sentinels.